# How can one efficiently group the nodes of a directed acyclic graph to make collective nodes?

Tags: matrices, algorithms, directed-graphs, adjacency-matrix

The adjacency matrix $A$ of the transitive closure of a directed acyclic graph can have a `checkerboard' pattern  like
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & ? & ? & ? & {\bf a}    &  {\bf a}   & b  &  b  &  b    &   {\bf c} \\
? & 0 & ? & ? & {\bf a}   &   {\bf a}  &  b &   b &   b   &   {\bf c} \\
? & ? & 0 & ? &  {\bf a}  &   {\bf a}  &  b &   b &   b   &   {\bf c}\\
? & ? & ? & 0 &  {\bf a}  &   {\bf a}  &  b &   b &   b  &    {\bf c}\\
 {\bf a}'  &{\bf a}'   &  {\bf a}' &  {\bf a}'  &  0 &  ? &   {\bf d} &  {\bf d}  &  {\bf d}   &  e  \\
{\bf a}'  &  {\bf a}' & {\bf a}'  &  {\bf a}'  &  ? & 0 &   {\bf d} &  {\bf d}  &  {\bf d}   & e   \\
 b'  &  b' &  b' &   b' &  {\bf d}'  &  {\bf d}'   &  0 & ? & ?  &  {\bf f} \\
 b'  &   b'&   b'&   b' & {\bf d}'   & {\bf d}'    &  ? & 0 & ?  &  {\bf f} \\
 b'  &   b'& b'  &   b' &  {\bf d}'  &  {\bf d}'  &  ? & ? & 0  &  {\bf f} \\
{\bf c}' &   {\bf c}' & {\bf c}'  &   {\bf c}' &  e'  & e'    &  {\bf f}'  & {\bf f}'  &  {\bf f}'   & 0\end{pmatrix}\ .
\end{equation}

The alternate light and heavy fonts are here just to make the `checkerboard'
pattern of the lettered constants apparent to the eye.

Each of the square blocks along the diagonal can be viewed as representing a set of nodes
that forms in a sense its own collective node; in my work it has been profitable to study
the related four-node graph whose adjacency matrix is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 &{\bf a} & b & {\bf c}\\
{\bf a}' & 0 & {\bf d} & e\\
 b' & {\bf d}' & 0 & {\bf f}\\
 {\bf c}' & e' & {\bf f}' & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}\ .$$

Question: given any adjacency matrix where the nodes have not already been assigned to sets that make the checkerboard pattern plain, how can this sort be efficiently done?

Answer (score 1):

This problem may belong just to the general mathematics of matrices and not require special knowledge of adjacency matrices at all, just knowledge of their basic properties:

The elements of an adjacency matrix are all $0$'s and $1$'s, and any above-diagonal element $A_{ij}$ and its below-diagonal
counterpart $A_{ji}$ must form one of the pairs $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(0,0)$.  The diagonal elements are $0$.

If an adjacency matrix represents a transitive closure,
then if $A_{ij}=1$ and $A_{jk}=1$, then $A_{ik}=1$.  The $4\times 4$, $2\times 2$, $3\times 3$, and $1\times 1$
blocks along the diagonal of the example above are otherwise arbitrary.

Some problems cannot be reduced to fewer nodes than in the original problem.

One can split the nodes into a set $I$ and a set $J$ and see if the set $I$ forms a collective node by checking if for each $j\in J$ all the values $A_{ij}$ for $i\in I$ match,
and all the values $A_{ji}$ also match.  If one finds a collective node, finding the next reduces to another solving the same general problem but with an adjacency matrix with fewer nodes, which is helpful; still, running through all the sets is slow and I am looking for a better approach.